# Como saber a versão do sistema operacional do usuário usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber se há como fazer para que quando a pessoa entre na minha página HTML, já identifique qual sistema operacional ela possui, e então habilite certos botões.

Por exemplo se ela possuir Windows 7, o programa para windows 8
será impossibilitado.

Não possuo nenhum código feito ainda, apenas gostaria de
saber se tal ideia é possível?

Answer (score 2):

É possível e existe uma dúzia de soluções pra isso na internet.

Atente a duas coisas:

Vai ser difícil você habilitar opções para todo e qualquer SO, pois existem inúmeros.

Novos SO surgem e o script não será capaz de identificá-los, sendo necessário uma constante revisão da solução, qualquer que seja.

Se for possível, tente se basear em outros fatores para sua decisão de código.

Comment: Obrigada, de verdade.. >o<

Comment: @Alis se minha resposta ajudou você, favor aceita-la. =)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var OSNome = "";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0")!= -1) OSNome="Windows 10";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.2") != -1) OSNome="Windows 8";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1") != -1) OSNome="Windows 7";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.0") != -1) OSNome="Windows Vista";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1") != -1) OSNome="Windows XP";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.0") != -1) OSNome="Windows 2000";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac")            != -1) OSNome="Mac/iOS";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("X11")            != -1) OSNome="UNIX";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux")          != -1) OSNome="Linux";
document.write('Seu Sistema Operacional: '+ OSNome);
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176790/4312593

Comment: Existe uma solução muito superior a essa aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706818/3976193

Comment: Obrigada.. muito Obrigada >o<

Comment: E o Windows 8.1?

Comment: Seu código me retorna "Windows 8" no Safari. No Chrome, FF, IE e Opera retorna correto, "Windows 10".

Comment: Neste código postado acima, é possível verificar com mais algumas implementações qual seria o windows da pessoa, se é 32 ou 64?

Comment: Dá sim, porém como os comentários acima não é a melhor abordagem. Segue o código: 

if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WOW64") != -1 || 
    window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win64") != -1 ){
   alert("Seu sitemas operacional é de 64 bit");
} else {
   alert("Seu sitemas operacional é de 32 bit");
}